# Continuity problems in decision based story application

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a decision based story. I.e you pick option a or b and the story changes depending on your choices. The problem I'm having is when I get so far into the story if I choose option a or b it kicks me back to a different part of the story that it shouldn't.

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView story;
    private Button buttonA;
    private Button buttonB;
    private int sPoint = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        story = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nView);
        buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTop);
        buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBottom);

        buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if ( sPoint == 1 | sPoint == 2 ) {
                   story.setText(R.string.V1_Story);
                   buttonA.setText(R.string.V1_Ans1);
                   buttonB.setText(R.string.V1_Ans2);
                   sPoint = 3;
               }
               else if (sPoint == 3 | sPoint == 4 ) {
                   story.setText(R.string.V3_Story);
                   buttonA.setText(R.string.V3_Ans1);
                   buttonB.setText(R.string.V3_Ans2);
                   sPoint = 5;
               }
               else if (sPoint == 5 | sPoint == 6 ) {
                   story.setText(R.string.V6_Story);
                   buttonA.setText(R.string.V6_Ans1);
                   buttonB.setText(R.string.V6_Ans2);
                   sPoint = 7;
               }
               else if (sPoint == 7) {
                   story.setText(R.string.V6_Story);
                   buttonA.setText(R.string.V6_Ans1);
                   buttonB.setText(R.string.V6_Ans2);
                   sPoint = 9;
               }
            }
        });

        buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ( sPoint == 2  | sPoint == 3 )  {
                    story.setText(R.string.V2_Story);
                    buttonA.setText(R.string.V2_Ans1);
                    buttonB.setText(R.string.V2_Ans2);
                    sPoint = 4;
                }
                else if (sPoint == 4 | sPoint == 5) {
                    story.setText(R.string.V4_Story);
                    buttonA.setText(R.string.V4_Ans1);
                    buttonB.setText(R.string.V4_Ans2);
                    sPoint = 6;
                }
                else if (sPoint == 6 | sPoint == 7 ) {
                    story.setText(R.string.V6_Story);
                    buttonA.setText(R.string.V6_Ans1);
                    buttonB.setText(R.string.V6_Ans2);
                    sPoint = 8;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You never use V5_Story ?

Comment: sorry, there are strings going up to v21_story - however I have just been testing the code thus far and it's not working so thought i'd leave them out for now until I figure out the issue.

Comment: You should use switch/case instead of so many if, it will be easier to read, code and debug

Comment: Describe the behaviour: you click what and the program kicks you where? But you need it to do what? We don't know what your intended behavior is and what your programm does.

Comment: `|` is very different than a logical OR operation `||`

Comment: Ok. So lets say The story reads, you are in room a. The two buttons at the bottom will say - would you like to go to room b or c. Lets say I select b - it takes me to the right room. The story now reads you are in room b. Would you like to go to room d or e. If I select the bottom button assigned as "e" it will display the wrong information in the story panel and I'll be somewhere else in the story that I shouldn't be. Sorry for the vague info I'm really struggling to describe it.